# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL memory leak

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks, nsdata

A Command Line Tool project was generated in XCode 5.1 for OSX, with the following simple code only to prove `NSData` memory leak.
The `NSData` object is never released. Every new instance in the loop increments memory leak. Autorelease doesn't work. Some of the direct release attempts results to syntax error. Any advice?
Sourrounding the NSData allocation with @autoreleasepool didn't help.
If I change NSData object to an NSString object, it also causes memory leak. So it seems to be a general memory deallocation problem in this Command line tool environment.
Returning from the memoryLeak method to the caller, the memory is still unrealased.

```
+ (void) memoryLeak {
    NSURL  *tileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/9/0/0.png"];

    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        NSData *tile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tileURL];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the memory released after the method completes? If so then there is no memory leak. The code, as written, already autoreleases the `NSData` object but it won't happen until after the method completes.

Comment: This `NSData` is an autorelease object, so it won't be deallocated until the autorelease pool is drained. If you want to see it deallocated after each iteration, add your own autoreleasepool inside the loop.

Comment: In a command line tool, you probably don't have a run loop, so autorelease pools will not be automatically drained.

Comment: Returning from the method to the caller, the memory is still unrealeased.

Comment: JWWalker, it may be right, but how to solve it in this command line environment? Embedding the NSData allocation line to a  @autoreleasepool {} block didn't solved the problem.

Comment: Are you showing all of the code in your question? What do you do with 'tile'?

Comment: Does `+(instancetype)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDataReadingOptions)readOptionsMask error:(NSError **)errorPtr;` with option `NSUncachedRead` work?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your code to:

```
+ (void) memoryLeak {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSURL  *tileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/9/0/0.png"];

        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            NSData *tile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tileURL];
        }
    }
    // Memory should be cleaned up here
}
```

Does it still leak?  If so looks like a bug, if not, you were possibly detecting leaks before the autorelease pool had a chance to clean it up.

Comment: Adding the `autoreleasepool` there doesn't really change much depending on how `memoryLeak` is called. If you are going to add an `autoreleasepool`, add it inside the loop. Then it will be useful.

Comment: I have already tried @autoreleasepool, with only the the NSData *tile ... line blocked. Didn't helped at all.